# Objective-C Why is my class method not visible to other methods in the class or to other object?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a class with multiple methods. I can instantiate this class from another object and call those methods. When I add a new method, I can not call it from another method within the class or from the other class. If I remove the parameter then I can see the method, but when I add it back I can not see the method. I have searched here and around the internet and I have made sure that I am importing the class and that the method is defined in the .h file. I am at a loss for what could be the problem.

The interface:

```
@interface npcgGetCharacterData : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResults;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property BOOL debug;
- (NSMutableString *)getRandomRace;
- (NSMutableString *)getRandomAlignment;
- (int)getRandomLevel;
- (NSMutableString *)getRandomNPCType;
- (NSMutableString *)getRandomNPCClass:(NSString *)entityClassType;
@end
```

The implementation:

```
#import "npcgGetCharacterData.h"
#import "RaceEntity+Properties.h"
#import "AlignmentEntity+Properties.h"
#import "NPCTypeEntity+Properties.h"

@implementation npcgGetCharacterData
@synthesize fetchedResults, managedObjectContext, debug;

- (NSMutableString *)getRandomRace {
    NSString *randomRace = [NSString alloc];
    NSArray *resultsArray;
    NSInteger intCount;
    RaceEntity *raceEntity;

    [self setupFetchedResultsController:@"RaceEntity" entityName:@"raceName" entityWhere:@"raceName != 'Any Race'"];
    debug = NO;
    [self performFetch];
    resultsArray = [fetchedResults fetchedObjects];
    intCount = [resultsArray count];
    raceEntity = [resultsArray objectAtIndex:arc4random() % intCount];
    randomRace = raceEntity.raceName;
    self.fetchedResults = nil;
    return randomRace.mutableCopy;
}

- (NSMutableString *)getRandomAlignment {
    NSString *randomAlignment = [NSString alloc];
    NSArray *resultsArray;
    NSInteger intCount;
    AlignmentEntity *alignmentEntity;

    [self setupFetchedResultsController:@"AlignmentEntity" entityName:@"alignmentName" entityWhere:@"alignmentName != 'Any Alignment'"];
    debug = NO;
    [self performFetch];
    resultsArray = [fetchedResults fetchedObjects];
    intCount = [resultsArray count];
    alignmentEntity = [resultsArray objectAtIndex:arc4random() % intCount];
    randomAlignment = alignmentEntity.alignmentName;
    self.fetchedResults = nil;
    return randomAlignment.mutableCopy;
}

- (NSMutableString *)getRandomNPCType {
    NSString *randomNPCType = [NSString alloc];
    NSArray *resultsArray;
    NSInteger intCount;
    NPCTypeEntity *npcTypeEntity;

    [self setupFetchedResultsController:@"NPCTypeEntity" entityName:@"npcTypeName" entityWhere:@"npcTypeName != 'Any Type'"];
    debug = NO;
    [self performFetch];
    resultsArray = [fetchedResults fetchedObjects];
    intCount = [resultsArray count];
    npcTypeEntity = [resultsArray objectAtIndex:arc4random() % intCount];
    randomNPCType = npcTypeEntity.npcTypeName;
    self.fetchedResults = nil;
    return randomNPCType.mutableCopy;
}

- (NSMutableString *)getRandomNPCClass:(NSString *)entityClassType {
    NSString *randomNPCClass = [NSString alloc];

    return randomNPCClass.mutableCopy;
}

- (int)getRandomLevel {
    int intRandomLevel = 0;

    intRandomLevel = (NSInteger)arc4random_uniform(20) + 1;
    return intRandomLevel;
}

- (void)setupFetchedResultsController:(NSString *)entityType entityName:(NSString *)entityName entityWhere:(NSString *)entityWhere{

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityType];
    if (entityWhere != nil) {
        [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:entityWhere]];
    }
    NSSortDescriptor *entityGroup = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:entityName ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSSortDescriptor *entityNameSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:entityName ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:entityGroup, entityNameSort, nil];

    self.fetchedResults = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] 
          initWithFetchRequest:request
          managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
          sectionNameKeyPath:nil
          cacheName:nil];
}

- (void)performFetch {
    if (self.fetchedResults) {
        if (self.fetchedResults.fetchRequest.predicate) {
            if (self.debug) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] fetching %@ with predicate: %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), self.fetchedResults.fetchRequest.entityName, self.fetchedResults.fetchRequest.predicate);
        } else {
            if (self.debug) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] fetching all %@ (i.e., no predicate)", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), self.fetchedResults.fetchRequest.entityName);
        }
        NSError *error;
        [self.fetchedResults performFetch:&error];
        if (error) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] %@ (%@)", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), [error localizedDescription], [error localizedFailureReason]);
        if (self.debug) {
            NSLog(@"Number of Objects = %i", [[self.fetchedResults fetchedObjects] count]);
        }
    } else {
        if (self.debug) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] no NSFetchedResultsController (yet?)", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    }

}

@end
```

The calling method. This is from a different object:

```
- (IBAction)GenerateNPCClick:(id)sender {
    npcgGenerateAttribute *nga = [npcgGenerateAttribute alloc];
    npcgGetCharacterData *ngc = [npcgGetCharacterData alloc];
    ngc.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    int intValue = 0;
    NSMutableString *textViewHolder = [NSMutableString alloc];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        intValue = nga.generate4D6;
        if (i == 0) {
            textViewHolder = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%d", intValue];
        } else {
            [textViewHolder appendString:@"\n"];
            [textViewHolder appendString:[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%d", intValue]];
        }
    }
    NSMutableString *strRace = ngc.getRandomRace;
    [textViewHolder appendString:@"\n"];
    [textViewHolder appendString:@"Race: "];
    [textViewHolder appendString:strRace];
    NSMutableString *strAlignment = ngc.getRandomAlignment;
    [textViewHolder appendString:@"\n"];
    [textViewHolder appendString:@"Alignment: "];
    [textViewHolder appendString:strAlignment];
    int intLevel = ngc.getRandomLevel;
    [textViewHolder appendString:@"\n"];
    [textViewHolder appendString:@"Level: "];
    [textViewHolder appendString:[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%d", intLevel]];
    NSMutableString *strNPCType = ngc.getRandomNPCType;
    [textViewHolder appendString:@"\n"];
    [textViewHolder appendString:@"NPC Type: "];
    [textViewHolder appendString:strNPCType];
    [ngc getRandomNPCClass:@"TestString"];
    self.textViewMessageSpace.text = textViewHolder;
}
```

The method that is giving me trouble is the getRandomNPCClass method. All of the other getRandom methods are working.

Forgot to include the error message: Property 'getRandomNPCClass' not on object of type 'npcgGetCharacterData *'. I get this when I try to call it from another object.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You don't appear to be *trying* to call that method anywhere. We can't tell you what you're doing wrong if you don't show us what you're doing.

Comment: Incidentally, you probably know this, but the implementation of `getRandomNPCClass:` is pretty busted.

Comment: they are not _class_ method but instance method. also what is the error/warning?

Comment: Chuck, I am not sure what you mean by the implementation is pretty busted. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is how you create the object:

```
npcgGetCharacterData *ngc = [npcgGetCharacterData alloc];
```

You're mussing the init message, so that's the reason why you get troubles when trying to use it as a properly initialized object. Since you haven't defined an init method, NSObject's init method will be used to initialize the object:

```
npcgGetCharacterData *ngc = [[npcgGetCharacterData alloc]init];
```

Additionally, I wish to remember that Objective-C convention about accessors id different from Java and C++. You don't call a getter getRandomNPCClass, but rather randomNPCClass.

Comment: Thanks for the information. That did not quite solve my issue, but got me to the answer. I was trying to use object. instead of [object. ]. That was ultimately why it was not working.